# Team Services Widget Script5:Access denied

Tags: widget, azure-devops

I've created a simple widget for Team Services dashboard.

It works perfectly fine on Firefox, with 0 errors in the console. But the widget fails to load on IE. The only error I get is:

[image]

What are some possible reasons for this? FYI, I'm running IE 11.0.9600.18282

Comment: Can you share the code in the html file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this, though I'm not entirely sure what I did fixed it. Here's a list of the things I changed. Some may be unrelated. Other may have solved the problem.

- Removed the `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the start of the document header
- Added `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` tag
- Use bower to manage my javascript files

After doing the above steps, it looks like my html started being read, and I started getting more useful error messages like my use of `Promise` and `Math.max(...array)` syntax.

After adding the relevant polyfills and IE 11 supported syntax everything now works.